# How to achieve rounded tabs in Android 2.1 +

Tags: java, android

Can anyone help me achieve rounded corners for the TabWidget with android 2.1 + .  I am basically trying to give the TabWidget a custom theme purely via xml configuration.  I have tried the following, but only the text color changes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="Tab_ForeColor">#6095C1</color>
    <color name="Tab_BackgroundColor">#411485</color>

    <style name="TestTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
        <item name="android:tabWidgetStyle">@style/TestTab</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TestTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/TestTextApperance</item>
        <item name="android:drawable">
            <drawable name="rounded_tab">
                <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:shape="rectangle">
                    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="@android:color/white" />
                    <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0.1dip"
                        android:bottomLeftRadius="0.1dip" android:topLeftRadius="15dip"
                        android:topRightRadius="15dip" />
                </shape>
            </drawable>
        </item>
    </style>

    <style name="TestTextApperance">
        <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/Tab_ForeColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

TIA

Andrew

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a Solution is setting an image with round corners over the tab, I know, cheesy solution but works.

```
tab = tabs.newTabSpec("tab_Busquedas");
tab.setContent(new Intent().setClassName("com.grapp", "com.grapp.homes").putExtras(bundle));
tab.setIndicator(null,null);
tabs.addTab(tab);
//here you set the image with rounded corners over the tab.
tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mytab_roundedcorners);
```

R.drawable.mytab_roundedcorners  will be a selector.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I am going to continue trying to look for a way to achieve this purely in xml if possible but I will accept your answer as it does do what I require. :-) Thanks.