# How to make styles for Rounted Rectangle button in android

Tags: android

I need xml styles for tab on or off state,whenever i click the button,display rounded rectangle on button.How can i make new style for given image.please give some tips for me
how to create styles for rounded rectangle like this image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that add rounded cornered images as a background to tab:

```
tab = tabs.newTabSpec("tab_Busquedas");
tab.setContent(new Intent().setClassName("com.grapp", "com.grapp.homes").putExtras(bundle));
tab.setIndicator(null,null);
tabs.addTab(tab);
//here you set the image with rounded corners over the tab.
tabs.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.mytab_roundedcorners);
```

This solution is posted at: [How to achieve rounded tabs in Android 2.1 +](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272182/how-to-achieve-rounded-tabs-in-android-2-1)

Comment: ,I want to create styles for this,don't use image,How is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the themes feature for the same.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

If you make use of this feature, maintainability will also be easy.

Regards,
SSuman185